# PostgreSQL: how to concat two character varying fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named res_partner in PostreSQL (v9.3) with the following columns:

```
phone              | character varying(64)       | 
mobile             | character varying(64)       |
```

I would like to concatenate both strings in the following way: "phone/mobile"

E.g:

```
+34942246573 / +3466243765
```

I'm trying the following in a SQL query:

```
SELECT (phone || '/' || mobile) AS PhoneNumbers  FROM res_partner;
```

The query works fine when the person has both 'phone' and 'mobile' populated:

```
myDB=# SELECT id, (phone || '/' || mobile) AS PhoneNumbers FROM res_partner WHERE id=43;
 id |    phonenumbers     
----+---------------------
 43 | 942686868/666666666
```

But if the person has only phone or mobile (but not both) populated, all I get is an emtpy string:

```
myDB=# SELECT id, (phone || '/' || mobile) AS PhoneNumbers FROM res_partner WHERE id=21;
 id | phonenumbers  
----+--------------
 21 | 
(1 fila)
```

But in this case I would expect to show something as "+54 341 324 9459 / " for PhoneNumbers

Why is showing an empty string at the output?

Answer (score 4):

That works according to the SQL standard. Any expression involving NULL yields null.

You can use the "null-safe" `concat()` function or probably better in your case `concat_ws()` which also takes care of not adding the separator is one of the inputs is null:

```
concat_ws('/', phone, mobile);
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1):

The result of you query is **not** an empty string - it's `null`, which is the result of performing any string operation on a `null` value.
To avoid this, you could `coalesce` the column in your query, and replace any `null`s with empty strings:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(phone, '') || '/' || COALESCE(mobile, '')) AS PhoneNumbers
FROM   res_partner;
```